# Captured image returns small size

Tags: java, android, image, size, android-camera-intent

I am capturing the image from camera. The captured image's size shows too small when captured. But later if I check in gallery the captured image size shows in MB.

I tried debugging the code, so while debugging I checked length of the file after image is captured the length shows 26956 bytes, and when I checked same image in gallery the size of the image is 1.3 MB.

Why the image size shows reduced when captured?

```
      private void cameraIntent() {

        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);

    }

     private void onCaptureImageResult(Intent data) {

        Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

 (thumbnail.getWidth()/2),(int)(thumbnail.getHeight()/2),true);

        thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bytes);
        File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");

        FileOutputStream fo;
        try {
            destination.createNewFile();
            fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
            fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
            fo.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        long size = destination.length();// here size of the image is too small

        selectFile = false;

        loadImageFromFile(destination.getAbsolutePath());

    }


      public void loadImageFromFile(String imageFile) {

        try {
            ExifInterface ei = new ExifInterface(imageFile);
            int orientation = ei.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                    ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED);

            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFile);

            Bitmap rotatedBitmap = null;

            switch (orientation) {
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                    rotatedBitmap = rotateImage(bitmap, 90);
                    break;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                    rotatedBitmap = rotateImage(bitmap, 180);
                    break;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                    rotatedBitmap = rotateImage(bitmap, 270);
                    break;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL:
                    rotatedBitmap = bitmap;
                    break;
                default:
                    rotatedBitmap = bitmap;
                    break;
            }

            if (rotatedBitmap != null) {

                if (selectFile && fileSizeInKB > 500) {
                    rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(rotatedBitmap, (int) (rotatedBitmap.getWidth() * 0.3), (int) (rotatedBitmap.getHeight() * 0.3), true);
                }

                else if(selectFile && fileSizeInKB > 1024){

                    rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(rotatedBitmap, (int) (rotatedBitmap.getWidth() * 0.2), (int) (rotatedBitmap.getHeight() * 0.2), true);
                }
                else if(selectFile && fileSizeInMB > 2){

                    rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(rotatedBitmap, (int) (rotatedBitmap.getWidth() * 0.1), (int) (rotatedBitmap.getHeight() * 0.1), true);
                }

                profileImageView.setImageBitmap(rotatedBitmap);
                selectedBitmap = rotatedBitmap;

                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                selectedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream); //replace 100 with desired quality percentage.
                byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

                File tempFile = File.createTempFile("temp", null, getCacheDir());
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
                fos.write(byteArray);

                Long size = tempFile.length();

                profileImage = tempFile;
            }

        } catch (IOException ex) {

        }
    }
```

I am scaling the images selected from gallery, I too want to scale the images captured from camera, but the size of the image  I am not getting appropriate.

Can anyone help for this please? Thank you...

Edit :

```
     private void cameraIntent() {

        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Create the File where the photo should go

            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {

            }
            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (photoFile != null) {
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
            }
        }

    }



     private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "image";
        File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );

        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        fileName = image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }

     private void onCaptureImageResult(Uri data) {

        try {

            Bitmap thumbnail = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), data);


            selectFile = false;

            long fileSizeInBytes = photoFile.length();
// Convert the bytes to Kilobytes (1 KB = 1024 Bytes)
            fileSizeInKB = fileSizeInBytes / 1024;
// Convert the KB to MegaBytes (1 MB = 1024 KBytes)
            fileSizeInMB = fileSizeInKB / 1024;

            loadImageFromFile(photoFile.getAbsolutePath());

        }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

 public void loadImageFromFile(String imageFile) {

    try {
        ExifInterface ei = new ExifInterface(imageFile);
        int orientation = ei.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED);

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFile);

        Bitmap rotatedBitmap = null;

        switch (orientation) {
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                rotatedBitmap = rotateImage(bitmap, 90);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                rotatedBitmap = rotateImage(bitmap, 180);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                rotatedBitmap = rotateImage(bitmap, 270);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL:
                rotatedBitmap = bitmap;
                break;
            default:
                rotatedBitmap = bitmap;
                break;
        }

        if (rotatedBitmap != null) {
            //

            if (selectFile && fileSizeInMB < 1 && fileSizeInKB > 500) {
                rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(rotatedBitmap, (int) (rotatedBitmap.getWidth() * 0.9), (int) (rotatedBitmap.getHeight() * 0.9), true);
            }

            else if(selectFile && fileSizeInMB < 2){

                rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(rotatedBitmap, (int) (rotatedBitmap.getWidth() * 0.3), (int) (rotatedBitmap.getHeight() * 0.3), true);
            }
            else if(selectFile && fileSizeInMB > 2){

                rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(rotatedBitmap, (int) (rotatedBitmap.getWidth() * 0.2), (int) (rotatedBitmap.getHeight() * 0.2), true);
            }
            else if(selectFile && fileSizeInMB > 3){

                rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(rotatedBitmap, (int) (rotatedBitmap.getWidth() * 0.1), (int) (rotatedBitmap.getHeight() * 0.1), true);
            }
            //  resize(rotatedBitmap,bitmap.getWidth()/2,bitmap.getHeight()/2);

            profileImageView.setImageBitmap(rotatedBitmap);
            selectedBitmap = rotatedBitmap;

            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            selectedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream); //replace 100 with desired quality percentage.
            byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

            File tempFile = File.createTempFile("temp", null, getCacheDir());
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
            fos.write(byteArray);

            Long size = tempFile.length();

            profileImage = tempFile;
        }

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        //  UiUtils.showAlert(getString(R.string.error),NewGroupAcvitity.this);
    }
}
```

Now with this code, when I capture the image after capturing it takes time to load on image view and show blank screen till the image is set to the image view.

Comment: you are compressing your bitmap

Comment: where? @VivekMishra

Comment: Here   `thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bytes);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the **Thumbnail** instead of the actual image.

To get the actual image you have to pass Image file uri to the Camera intent as `MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT`

Sample :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);//photoURI - file uri where you want the image to be saved
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
```

Refer https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskPath for the required steps and complete code.

---

To get a scaled `Bitmap` from file path

```
    int targetW = 800;
    int targetH = 1000;

    // Get the dimensions of the bitmap
    BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath, bmOptions);
    int photoW = bmOptions.outWidth;
    int photoH = bmOptions.outHeight;

    int scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW / targetW, photoH / targetH);

    // Decode the image file into a Bitmap
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
    bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath, bmOptions);
```

Comment: from where to pass uri? in which method?

Comment: Have you checked the link I mentioned?

Comment: Go through the google training page, still if you find any difficulty, post it here.

Comment: Now inside `onCaptureImageResult()`, use image_file_uri (photoFile in your case) instead of `data`.

Comment: and how to get bitmap from this uri? can you please guide me with whole process?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130172/discussion-between-sid-and-monish-kamble).

Comment: @Sid : Sorry I can't chat as it is blocked by my office firewall. If you have any query/issue post it here.

Comment: while capturing image from camera If I am using original captured image rather than bitmap it takes time to load the image on image view.

Comment: Because you are doing image compression(which is heavy and time consuming) first and then setting the image on imageView. First set the imageView and do the image compression on later stage probably on a background thread.